# advanced filter applied to two fact tables

Tags: powerbi, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have two facts and dimensions tabels that i need to filter with one filter. both dim tabels have the same columns marked with yellow in the picture. The blue line is the relation between the tabels. right now there is no relation that makes it possiable to connect the dim agentjobs with the fact SSIS and the same with dim SSIS and Fact Agent.

can somebody help me explain which relation i need to create to be able to filter both the fact agent and fact SSIS from a filter with customer_code, servername and instancename.

[image]

right now the filter only filter the Agent table because the customer_code, servername and instancename is from the din agent table.
[image]

Comment: You should create your dimensions in a way that you can use them in both your facts. e.g. create a Customer dimension and a Server dimension

Comment: instead of 2/3 different dimensions would it not be better to make a calcualted tabel with customer_code, servername and instancename?